# How to read strings from char array separated by null in c?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have a char array contains string separated by null. I have the indexes for the strings present in the char aarray. How to read string from this char array using index and are separated by null.

e.g. I have following char array,

```
char *buf = ['\0', 'b', 'c', 's', '\0', 'n', 'e', 'w', '\0', 'n', 'x', 't', '\0'];
```

I have the indexes for these strings e.g 
index 1 for **bcs** string 
index 5 for **new** string
index 9 for **nxt** string

How read these string using index from this char array?

Comment: buf + index gives you the string. Like buf + 1 for the first string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the simple question, I got the answer, We can get string from char array  as follows:
- Get the address of index of which string you want to get
- Print the string

```
char* str = &buf[index];
if(str)
printf("string is : %s\n", str);
```

Comment: `str` cannot ever be `NULL` so the test is obsolete.

Comment: Or `char* str = buf + index;`, as suggested to you in a comment by @Selçuk Cihan.

Answer (score 1):

A more general approach would be to go through `buf` until you have printed all strings, i.e., without using indexes.

The problem is then how to identify the end of the (used part of) the buffer. A general trick for that is to terminate the buffer with an extra null character. The following demonstrates this:

```
char buf[] = {'\0', 'b', 'c', 's', '\0', 'n', 'e', 'w', '\0', 'n', 'x', 't', '\0', '\0'};

void f(void)
{
    char *s= buf;
    do {
        if (*s==0) {
            if (*(s+1)==0) break;
            s++;
        }
        puts(s);
        while (*s) s++;
    } while(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it.I didn't do any safety check though, the code just shows how to read strings from character array separated by null terminator.And whenever you are assigning multiple values to an array use this brackets [] rather use curly braces {}

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
   char buf[] = {'\0', 'b', 'c', 's', '\0', 'n', 'e', 'w', '\0', 'n', 'x', 't', '\0'};
   int indx = 0;
   printf("Which index to read from:");
   scanf("%d", &indx);
   for(int i = indx; buf[i] != '\0'; i++){
    printf("%c", buf[i]);
  }
}
```